# What happened with this family when they arrived Quebec in 1871?

Tags: immigration, canada, quebec, 1870s, norway

I am searching for this family who emigrated from Trondheim, Norway to Quebec, Canada 4th March 1871. They arrived Quebec with the ship "Franklin" and I can't find anything more about the family, so I need help figuring out where they settled in Canada.

- Hans (Benjamin) Nilsen, born: 4th June 1834, Married: 17th October 1858, Bindal, Nordland, Norway.
- Wife: Bergithe (Birgitte Sofie) Olsdatter, born: 27th January 1838, marriage: 17th October 1858 Bindal, Nordland, Norway
- Daughter: Hansine Hansen (Hansdatter), born: 10th July 1860, Bindal, Nordland, Norway
- Son, Johan (Petter Christian) Hansen, born: 6th July 1862, Bindal, Nordland, Norway
- Son: Nils (Christian Bull) Hansen, born: 5th August 1858, Bindal, Nordland, Norway
- Son: Ole (Frederick Beyer) Hansen, born: 25th July 1868, Bindal, Nordland, Norway
- Son: Jacob Hansen: He was only eight days old when they left Norway and he was not on the passenger list when they arrived Quebec 4th March 1871.

Comment: Hi, Olav, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Can you tell us the source of the information in your question?  Do you have the passenger list for the Franklin, emigration records from Norway, etc?  Including a brief source list helps us see what you're looking at without having to guess.  Hope you enjoy the site!

Comment: @Olav What resources have you searched? Canada's censuses are available on the Libraries and Archives Canada website (free) [http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/Pages/discover.aspx ] and through ancestry.com (subscription site). Even FamilySearch has Canadian census indexes (but not the page images). Age is slightly off, but a possible match to Hans Nilsen is in the 1911 household of son? Nils Hansen in Thunder Bay and Rainy River District, Ontario.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried this link: [bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/census/Pages/census.aspx] but I can not find anything more about the family here.

Comment: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/279/bgwiehle

Comment: We still don't know whether you need help finding resources or whether the problem is how to use them. Both LAC & Ancestry have the Hans Nilsen I found indexed as Haus Nelsen [http://data2.collectionscanada.gc.ca/1911/jpg/e002023484.jpg &  http://search.ancestry.ca/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=1911Canada&indiv=try&h=9078771 ]

Comment: Thank you -@bgwiehle. This is the right family I'm looking for. I try to find descendants who are alive and resident in Canada today, and maybe get in touch with them. But I find it difficult to find resources and use them.

Comment: I realize this question is from 2+ years ago, and I see that the OP has not returned since a few days after asking the question, but since Norway keeps excellent records, I was able to find the parish records of this family's _udflyttede_, or [emigration](https://media.digitalarkivet.no/en/view/6640/34453/11), and infant Jacob is not there. Also, they registered their leaving on 2 May 1871, so they probably didn't leave on 4 March. Also, Nils Christian is 6 here and on the arrival records, so probably born in 1865 not 1858. There is no record of Jacob's birth in the parish records, but...

Comment: ... if the family departed before he was baptized, he wouldn't appear in the books, which are really baptism books and not birth books. [Family's arrival in Quebec](https://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/immigration/immigration-records/passenger-lists/passenger-lists-quebec-port-1865-1900/Pages/image.aspx?Image=e003533534) and the [book](https://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/immigration/immigration-records/passenger-lists/passenger-lists-1865-1922/Pages/item.aspx?IdNumber=792&) shows the ship departed Trondheim, Norway on 3 or 4 May 1871, arrived Quebec City, Quebec on 2 July 1871.